# delete till the end of line (exclusive of current letter)

Tags: vim, intellij-idea, ideavim

I know d$ or D will delete till the end of line including the letter on the cursor? Is there a way to do this excluding the letter on the cursor? I did :h d in vim and browsed around a bit but couldn't find if this is possible. I am trying to do this in AppCode with IdeaVim plugin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In normal mode, you could do `lD` or `ld$`.

Comment: That works. It is 3 keystrokes though. Can we do it in 2/1 keystrokes. Vim is spoiling me :-)

Comment: @user674669 If you really need a fast shortcut, you can put something like this line in your _vimrc file: `map <C-D> lD`. Now you just need to type `CTRL+D`.  You can also remap a single letter. For example, using just `X`: `map X lD`.

Comment: Thanks @src. It is a good approach. Just wanted to point out that IdeaVim plugin doesn't seem to support :map

Comment: As of version 0.33, released 2014-04-28, IdeaVim now does support :map.